# two or more data types in declaration specifiers for typedef float _Float32;

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm porting a pretty old C (and a bit of C++) code basis from KEIL OS to Linux 32 bit.

When compiling with gcc/g++ 6.3 to 6.5 it works ok, when trying to do the same with gcc > 7.0 (tested with 7.3 and 8.2 on ubuntu 18.04) I get compilation errors:

```
/usr/include/bits/floatn-common.h:207:15: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 typedef float _Float32;
               ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/bits/floatn-common.h:244:16: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 typedef double _Float64;
                ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/bits/floatn-common.h:261:16: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 typedef double _Float32x;
                ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/bits/floatn-common.h:278:21: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 typedef long double _Float64x;
```

The compiler header (`/usr/include/bits/floatn-common.h:261:16`) file contains the following part:

```cpp
# if __HAVE_FLOAT32

#  if !__GNUC_PREREQ (7, 0) || defined __cplusplus
typedef float _Float32;
#  endif

#  if !__GNUC_PREREQ (7, 0)
#   define __builtin_huge_valf32() (__builtin_huge_valf ())
#   define __builtin_inff32() (__builtin_inff ())
#   define __builtin_nanf32(x) (__builtin_nanf (x))
#   define __builtin_nansf32(x) (__builtin_nansf (x))
#  endif

# endif
```

Which tells me that this is only related to `gcc > 7.0`

most of the issues related to this error are missing ";" in structs or doing something like

```cpp
void int myFunction(void){}
```

though I think this is not the case here because it appears in different compilation units and it works with previous versions of `gcc/g++`

`using glibc version 2.2`7

**My question:** is there a way to disable this new compiler feature or eventually a hint from the community where to start searching

Comment: The "pretty old code" appears to be including non-public headers in some non-standard way that no longer works. The issue is not with the headers, but with the code that needs to be fixed. You need to look at the code being compiled, get rid of references to non-public headers, and figure out which headers it needs to include instead of them.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `is there a way to disable this new compiler feature` - this is not really a compiler future. `two or more data types in declaration specifiers` - is `_Float32` in the code a macro defined in your program? Track it down, remove it. `_Float32` should be defined by the compiler. Looks to me like your code does `#define _Float32 float` then `typedef float float;`....

Comment: @KamilCuk I already looked for those macros, not present in the code...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm just adding "math.h"
`
In file included from /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/floatn.h:120:0,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:43,
`

Comment: If it's this standard header, and the code being compiled doesn't have any bizarre `#define`s that might clash with the ones in the internal header files, then this would indicate a broken compiler configuration or a corrupted compiler or header installations.

Comment: You need to track it down. This `are missing ";" in structs` I don't understand, can you post some of the errors you are getting? Then find out where elsewhere is _Float32 defined? Can you create the smallest .c file / transaction unit that exhibits the problem? You need to find the smallest reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: Looks like gcc 7+ has `_Float32` as a compiler built-in.  Obviously `__GNUC_PREREQ (7, 0)` is intended to disable this code if gcc 7+ is in use. You could try investigating why that test is not taking the correct path

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue:

Somewhere in the source code there was a

```
#undef __GNUC__
```

Which was produced by a broken code generation tool...

By doing this, all inclusions of math.h or wchar.h were broken...